# CakePHP redirection in beforefilter AppController

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, AppController beforeFilter function I tried to redirect but it not working...
I am getting Browser error: Too many redirects.

```
if ($this->Session->read('Check.val')) 
{
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action' => 'login')); exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, if that value *does* exist in the session, then it’s always going to redirect.

It looks like you’re building a login system. Check out [CakePHP’s built-in authentication component](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).